# TypeError: action.payload.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Reducer.js

```js
case UpdateTotalPrice:
    const allItemsPrices = action.payload.map(item => item.price * item.quantity);
    const totalPrice = allItemsPrices.reduce((acc,item)=>acc + item ,0);
    return {...state, totalPrice}
```

actions.js

```js
    export const updateTotalPrice =(selectedItems)=>{
        return { type: UpdateTotalPrice, payload: selectedItems};
    };
```

I am trying to get rid of this error but I don't know if the logic is okay, and I don't know where the problem comes from.

Comment: can you console.log `selectedItems` and share it with us?